# this.on("click", function() {}) doesn't work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a task list in JS but have some problems. I push all new Task objects into TaskListHolder.tasks array, and the issue is that click events inside these objects don't work. For instance, I put first object into array - checkClickEvent works... but when I put second object into array then click event of first object doesn't work, however, the second one works, and so on. What the problem is???

```
function Task(params) {
        this.title = params.title;
        this.description = params.description;
        this.id = params.id;
        this.deleteBtnClickHandler = params.deleteBtnClickHandler;
        this.createHtml();
        this.html.on("click", this.deleteBtnClickHandler);
    }

createNewTask: function() {
            var _this = this;
            var task = new Task({
                title: _this.openedPopup.find(".task-title").val(),
                description: _this.openedPopup.find(".task-description").val(),
                id: _this.generateID.apply(this),
                deleteBtnClickHandler: _this.checkClickEvent.bind(this)
                // deleteBtnClickHandler: _this.deleteTask.bind(this, setTimeout(function() {
                //     return task.id;
                // }, 0))
            });
            this.TaskListHolder.add(task);
            this.openedPopup.remove();
        },
checkClickEvent: function() {
            console.log("Yep! I'm working...)");
        },
```

Comment: I think you are confusing many things. You are trying to use jQuery syntax on something that is not a jQuery object  - and as far as I can see does not even exist. There is nothing in your snippet of code that seems right

Comment: `var _this = this;` creates a dom element from a possible jQuery object passed - that means jQuery methods no longer exist on it

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks)))  here is a link for a full version of the project)
https://codepen.io/olegov99/pen/KbreQY

Comment: What do I click to show the issue? I strongly suggest you use the $ prefix on all jquery objects so they are recognisable. this.$div.on("click" makes more sense than this.html.on